# ui-sref-opts={reload: true} not reloading the controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, ui-sref

I have a link where I want to use a ui-sref. Even if the target is the same as the source I want it to reload.
For this reason I am using: `ui-sref='newState' ui-sref-opts='{reload: true}'`
But this does not work...
If I use: `$state.go('newState', {}, {reload: true})` it is working fine.
Any ideas?

Comment: You're missing the parenthesis for the ui-sref-opts directive. ui-sref-opts="{reload: true}" should work.

Comment: Thanks for the info. updated the question. i already used paranthesis in the original code :(

Comment: Maybe use double instead of single quotes?

Comment: No this doesn't change anything. But thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This should help:

```
ui-sref-opts="{reload: true, notify: true}"
```